# Grails- change the submit button to fa icom

Tags: grails, icons

I have to change the submit button which the submitToRemoye creates to fa fa-check (fa icon).

```
<g:form url="[controller: 'connectionRequest', action: 'accept']" class="">
       <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${connectionInstance.id}"/>
        <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 50%">
              <g:submitToRemote class="fa fa-check" id="accept-button"
                 url="[controller: 'connectionRequest', action: 'accept']"
                 update="connectionRequest${i}" />
 </div>
/g:form>
<r:script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#accept-button,#ignore-button').parent().addClass('fa fa-check');
    });


</r:script>
```

It doesn't work well

Answer (score 0):

Change the tag '`<g:submitToRemote...`' to `<button type='submit'><i class='fa fa-ok'/>Send</button>`

Change the tag '`<g:form...`' to '`<g:formRemote...`'

Comment: and if I need more buttons in the form like ignore?

Comment: You can add action in name attribute, like this: <button name="_action_delete" type="submit">...

Answer (score 0):

If you got a generated GSP file using scaffolding, you better try to search the 'g:submitToRemote' class definition in the CSS files you got.
Either you can right click on the submit button -> 'Inspect element' and find the icon name and search it over your files to see who is using it.